# Create index to reduce costs in database?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have to migrate queries to stored procedures, and i get TAF(Table Access Full), I want create index for better performance, I have next:

```
CREATE INDEX MY_INDEX2 ON OWNER.TABLE_NAME(FIELD);
```

And I get next:

```
INDEX_NAME      UNIQUE  LOGGING DEGREE  COLUM_NAME  ORDER   POSITION    INDEX_OWNER
MY_INDEX        Y       NO      1       MY_FIELD    Asc     1           MY_OWNER
MY_INDEX2       N       YES     1       MY_FIELD1   Asc     1           MY_OWNER
```

Any know how change position of MY_INDEX2 to 2?

And how better my MY_INDEX2?
For example, add diferent order and use bitmap index.

And any explain me what signify degree?

Thanks!

Comment: You realize that an index doesn't necessarily mean Table Access Full will be avoided in all queries, right? If a query needs to process a large number of rows (say, more than 70% of all the rows in a table), it is more efficient to retrieve all the rows and ignore the ones that are not needed, than it is to use an index for access. Make sure you don't add unnecessary indexes, since they have costs, they don't just have benefits.

Comment: To expand on @mathguy's answer; it's all about COST. The optimizer will evaluate different execution plans, and choose the one with the lowest cost. Where does it get the cost from? Statistics!. So, get an execution plan for you query and lets see what the optimizer thinks. Do this: alter session set statistics_level=ALL;  Then run your query. Then get the output of select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST' ) )

Answer (score 1):

To answer your SPECIFIC questions...

> Any know how change position of MY_INDEX2 to 2?

An index does not have a position.  However, a column within the index has a position. In a single column index, it would be position 1.  For composite indexes, the position represents the order of the column in the index.

> And how better my MY_INDEX2? For example, add diferent order and use
>   bitmap index.

How much better is your index for performance?  It may not be better.  It all depends on your data and data model.  Check your explain plan.  Create the new index.  Re-check your explain plan.  There is more to it, but start with that.  Only use a bitmap index in a data warehouse/reporting environment where the data is not changing.

> And any explain me what signify degree?

You can specify a degree of parallelism for your index.  A degree of 1 is equivalent of NOPARALLEL.  Keep it NOPARALLEL until you understand parallelism in the database.